# Background Beacon detection with Android Beacon Library

Tags: java, android, ibeacon, beacon

I'm using Android Beacon Library to scan for iBeacons. I'm using the **HM-10** BLE module as a iBeacon. My problem is when i used the Android Beacon Library Sample codes, Nothing happens at all.
As mentioned in the sample code for **starting an App in the Background**, i created a new java class named "Backgroud" and the MainActivity class.

I want my application to **start** when a Beacon is detected when the app is not opened. Or **show a notification (Toast)** when the app is open.

I'm want also to know, what do we put in the **MainActivity** class.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is my AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:name=".Background"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

This is my MainActivity Java class :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
            setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
        }
    }
```

This is my Background Java class :

```
public class Background extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private static final String TAG = ".Background";
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "App started up");
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        // To detect proprietary beacons, you must add a line like below corresponding to your beacon
        // type.  Do a web search for "setBeaconLayout" to get the proper expression.
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24"));

        // wake up the app when any beacon is seen (you can specify specific id filers in the parameters below)
        Region region = new Region("com.example.myapp.boostrapRegion", null, null, null);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
        // Don't care
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call");
        // This call to disable will make it so the activity below only gets launched the first time a beacon is seen (until the next time the app is launched)
        // if you want the Activity to launch every single time beacons come into view, remove this call.
        //regionBootstrap.disable();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        // IMPORTANT: in the AndroidManifest.xml definition of this activity, you must set android:launchMode="singleInstance" or you will get two instances
        // created when a user launches the activity manually and it gets launched from here.

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "A Beacon is detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
        // Don't care
    }
}
```

Comment: What specific tests have you run that have not worked out as you expect?  What do you see in LogCat when you run your program?  Do you see "App started up"?  Do you see "Got a didEnterRegion call"?  Do you know your beacon is working by trying to see it with an off-the-shelf beacon detector app?

Comment: Hello David, in fact i don't see "Got a didEnterRegion call". and yes my beacon is working and i can detect it with scanning apps. All i want is that when the app detects the beacon, a toast message show up.

Comment: Do you get a callback to `didDetermineStateForRegion`?  If so, what is the value of arg0?  This should be an indicator of whether or not you are *already* inside the region.  If already inside, you must exit the region before you will bet a second didEnterRegion event -- even across app restarts.